# New IP address with TSOCKS

Tags: ip-address, tor

I am using `tsocks` on my Ubuntu machine and I have it all set up so that if I run

```
wget -q -O - checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

in my normal shell I get my real IP address, and if I run

```
tsocks wget -q -O - checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

I get another IP address like I should.

My question is how do I make the `tsocks` command return with a different 'different address'; in other words establish a new identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tsocks` is a simple wrapper for SOCKS5 proxies, it has nothing to do with identities or Tor in general.

You will have to use a Tor control program such as Vidalia.

Comment: `tsocks` over `tor` will cause traffic for the program you are `tsocks`-ing to use the Tor network.  This makes that specific program act as though it has a different IP address.  It does NOT affect any other programs or your machine as a whole.  Tor only supports TCP so even if someone was running a DHCP server to "give you" a different IP it couldn't happen as DHCP runs on UDP.  It would also break your current connection with the Tor circuit.

Comment: @ultrasawblade: This does not involve DHCP in any way. Tor can be told to simply open a new circuit with a different exit node.